# check the json data for comparing in extjs

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I created a simple login page using extjs MVC to understand MVC architecture of extjs. As you can see below, I am trying to get the json data into the store and then I will check each username and password in that data with the entered login credentials. The thing in which I am confused right now is that, how to check the username and password from the retrieved json data present in `store` folder into the `view` folder? (Below code is only the related code with the problem)

I aware that this could invoke security threats, as I am checking on client side.

**'view' folder --> Code.js**

```
function checkJson(username, password){
    //if matched, return true.
    //else, return false.
}
```

**'model' folder --> Code.js**

```
Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: ['name', 'email']
});
```

**'store' folder --> Code.js**

```
Ext.define('LoginPage.store.Code', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   model: 'LoginPage.model.Code',
   autoLoad: true,


   proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'data/loginResponse.json',
            update: 'data/checkCredentials.json'  //Contains:  {"success": true}
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'loginResponse',
            successProperty: 'success'
        }
   }
});
```

**loginResponse.json**

```
{
"form": {
   "login": [
     {
       "username": "venkat",
       "password": "123"
     },
     {
       "username": "admin",
       "password": "345"
     }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your checking part of the code to the Controller (views are for presentation). In view define some form with login and password fields. In Controller catch `click` event on form `OK` (`Login`) button, get form values (login + password), then use `Ext.data.Store.query()` method to find wether credentials fits or not like:

Look [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control) for examples how to use controllers in MVC to catch events;

In your Controller put:

```
init: function() {
    this.control({
        '#form_ok_button': { // this is the `id` property of your form's Login button
            click: function(button) {
                 var fValues = button.up('form').getValues(); // Assume your button is bound to the form
                 // Or you can use `Controller.refs` property (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs) to get form
                 var matched = store.query('username', fValues.username);
                 if(matched.length && matched[0].get('password') === fValues.password) {
                     // login OK!
                 }
            }
        }
    });
},
```

How to use `refs` (in Controller):

```
refs: [
   { ref: 'usernameField', selector: '#username_field' }, // username field id is "username_field"
   { ref: 'passwordField', selector: '#password_field' }, // password field id is "password_field"
],

init: function() {  
   this.control({
       '#form_ok_button': {
            click: function() {
                // with `refs` autogetters are created for every `ref`:
                var username_field = this.getUsernameField();
                var password_field = this.getPasswordField();
            }
        }
   })
}
```

You can read about `referencing` [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/mvc_pt3).

For every Store in `Ext.app.Controller.stores` array autogetters are created too (in your case for `Code` store use `this.getCodeStore()` inside controller).

**Here is the flow:**

1. You get username and password field values with `this.getUsernameField()` and `this.getPasswordField()`;
2. You `query()` store for username
3. If username exist in store, you check if password fits.

Comment: Thanks for response. What is `form` here?

Comment: +1 Thank you for making me understand the structure clearly :). The thing is that my button is not bound to any form, it is just present in a container. The container also has two textfields in which the username and password are present. I am getting those textfield values and trying to match in a function i.e `function checkJson(username, password)` as shown in my post.

Comment: Also, I am getting an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined ` how to define the store variable?(`var store = ?`) please help I am new.

Comment: Thanks, I just added indentation for my understanding. (hope you don't mind)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know great stuff in extjs but I think you haven't understand what I am trying to get here. I want to check each and every username and password values present in the 'store' folder, Code.js (retrieved from json) in a function present in 'controller` folder (changed from 'view' folder to 'controller' folder on your good suggestion). The function is `function checkJson(username, password)` in 'controller' folder. This function returns true if username and password matches, else false. Sorry, if I made you confused earlier by my poor english. :)

Comment: You want to check check each and every username and password values present in the 'store' against what?

Comment: against the user entered values in the text fields (ie. username and password textfields)

Comment: Sorry, ya it does. :). The thing is that I can't understand how you are calling the `store` in the 'controller' folder without even declaring it as variable. when I tried your code, I am getting error --> `Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined `. I am not sure how to declare it.. `var store = ?`.

Comment: Explanation is in my answer - "For every Store in ..."

Comment: I tried `var store = this.getCodeStore();`, I am getting error --> `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getCodeStore'` . (The store is extended to `Ext.data.Store`.)

Comment: I even tried `var store = this.getStore()` which is showing error --> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined ` Please help.

Comment: Atlast, I tried `var store = Ext.create('LoginPage.store.Code');` which is showing `0` items when I checked in Chrome console. Is my 'store' folder Code.js file is ok? or I am declaring the variable wrong.

Comment: Please check my edited post. Added the 'model' folder's **Code.js** file too. The 'controller' folder's **Code.js** file is similar to what you explained here.

Comment: post your `Controller.js` file. Before read carefully - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/mvc_pt1, http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/mvc_pt2, http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/mvc_pt3

Comment: sorry for late response.. Please check the following link http://stackoverflow.com/q/14852700/1577396. I added all the files here.. If you get confused please tell me. I will look after those links which you provided now.. But I don't have time right now to go through them. As I want to submit this asap.

Comment: please have a look at this link  http://stackoverflow.com/q/14854089/1577396. (I deleted the previous link as it was messy to understand)